# Nunjucks Json templating client side

Tags: json, nunjucks

```
    Hi Team,  
    I have a html page and 'onload' of the DOM I am getting a json data object from the back-end service.
```

[{"value": "New", "id": "ab"},{"value": "Open", "id": "cd"},{"value": "Close", "id": "ef"}]
        I just wanted to transform that json object to below format with nunjucks templating.  new ab
 open cd
 close ef
could you please help me in implementing this

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
    {% for item in data %}
      {{item.value}} {{item.id}}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

where data is your array of objects.